# How to fix "The * or -> operator must be applied to a pointer"?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, assignment-operator

I'm studying about Assignment Operators in C# using Visual Studio 2019 but the script is not running due the error code CS0193.

First I changed the position of "+" add sign behind the "=" equivalent sign just like that { c =+ a } but it only work with add and sub. I want to use { c *= a} but getting following error.

```
            int a = 21;

            int c =+ a;

            Console.WriteLine("1. Value of c is {0}", c );

            Console.WriteLine("2. Binery of c is {0}", Convert.ToString(c, 2));

            Console.ReadLine();
```

well according to my book it should work like ( x -= y ), (x += y), (x *= y) …
but in Visual studio 2019 is work like (x =- y), (x =+ y), error, error …

Error code: CS0193

Description: The * or -> operator must be applied to a pointer.

Comment: Output of above code is 1. Value of c is 21
2. Binery of c is 10101

Comment: What is the book that you mention?

Comment: What do you expect `int c *= a;` to do?

Comment: what is your intention of " I changed the position of "+" add sign behind the "=" equivalent sign " ? why did you do this? what kind of behaviour did you expect?

Comment: experimental behaviour ;p

Comment: Tutorials Point C# learing book name anyway ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing declaration and assignment. You can only use `*=` (and `+=` and `-=` and `++`) on an already declared variable. So you need to do something like:

```
int a = 21;

int c = 1;

c *= a;
```

Answer (score 6):

The operators *end* with `=`, not start with `=`.  So use `*=` `+=` `-=` `/=`.

When you type `int c =+ a` that parsed as:

```
int c = +a; // evuivalent to: int c = a
```

When you type `int c =* a` that is parsed as:

```
int c = *a; // error unless a is a pointer.
```